# Atom/Electron dynamic HTML paths

Tags: javascript, file, templates, electron

I'm very new to Electron so it might be a stupid question, however: my application uses multiple windows, so naturally I wanted to implement a (very) basic template engine to avoid recreating pages' header and footer on every page. So I did this:

```
function setWindowContent(template)
{
    FileSystem.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'layout.html'), 'utf-8', function(error, layoutCode){
        if (!error) {
            FileSystem.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, template+'.html'), 'utf-8', function(error, content){
                if (!error){
                    content = layoutCode.replace('{{main_content}}', content);

                    mainWindow.webContents.loadURL('data:text/html,' + content);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

And it works, however for some reason I can't include any css or js files, it just can't find them. The "require" statements work, although the path is quite long because of the scope. So this works:

```
<script>window.$ = window.jQuery = require('./../../../../../../js/jquery-2.2.1.min.js');</script>
```

But this doesn't:

```
<link href="./css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

As well as this:

```
<link href="./../../../../../../css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

Any tips?
On a side note, do I need to somehow close the file pointer after reading the contents, or is this done automatically?

The app folder looks like this:

```
├── css/
│   └── style.css
├── js/
├── node_modules/
├── main.js
├── package.json
├── layout.html
├── index.html
```

I didn't list the contents of "node_modules" folder, as it would take a few pages, because it's installed locally via npm install.

Comment: can you post your structure folder ?

Comment: Try the path without a dot?  ````/css/style.css```` without the dot will include from the root path, is that maybe what you were trying to do? ````./css/style.css```` with the dot refers to the current directory which is why you had to include the longer path if you are heavily nested.

Comment: @Chrissi: Tried that with and without the preceding dot, and it still wouldn't work :(

Comment: `href="./css/style.css"` this should work , any error in your console ?

Comment: @John The ./css/style.css only works if I call loadURL on browser window, e.g., mainWindow.loadURL('file://'+__dirname + '/layout.html'); But I am using mainWindow.webContents.loadURL('data:text/html,' + content); to combine two files together. It does display the template just as it should, but the paths do not work.

Comment: Try adding a base path at the top of your head: `<base href="/">`. Also why are you using `mainWindow.webContents` and not just `mainWindow.loadURL`?